# How do I disable terminal control escape sequences in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, parser

I am writing software that interacts with an embedded device running a version of busybox Linux. Basically, I am just sending commands to the device and parsing the output from the commands . The commands are executed either on the linux shell directly or on the command line of an in-house CLI application running on the device.

Everything works fine except that the output is peppered with [terminal control escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm). On terminal applications such as teraterm or putty, these escape sequences do useful things like color errors red and other nice features for a pleasant user interface.

The problem is that I have to programmatically parse the output from the commands and account for things like "(esc)[2k" in the output.

For example, a typical send/receive interaction where I send a command, "my-cmd" would go like this...

```
[send] my-cmd
[receive] my-cmd <esc>[2Kprompt> my-cmd
output of the command
prompt>
```

What I would really like to do is to turn off these escape sequences. **Is this something that can be done on the command-shell at the beginning of a session? Or is there no way around this other than filtering the output?**

Comment: There is probably a better way, but you might be able to do this on a per-command basis. What are the commands you are sending? I am thinking about things like `ls` being an alias for `ls --colors=tty` and grep pointing to `grep --color` and suchlike. You might be able to avoid the escape sequences if you use, for example, `/bin/ls` instead of `ls`.

Comment: @terdon there is a simpler way. simply use `\ls` instead of `ls` and it will bypass all aliases.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I will try that with the shell commands. Does the backslash prefix apply to _all_ shell commands? Too bad there isn't a way to globally turn the behavior off. Also I have to hope that the in-house commands behave properly.

Comment: I just learned about this a half an hour ago but it is actually a way of quoting. A quoted command name causes BASH to ignore any aliases. It should work with all _aliases_ not all commands but most cases where you have color output without specifying an option are aliases. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6162903/1081936) for some more info.

Comment: Redirecting output (e.g. through `cat`, into a file or a named pipe) might also work. You'll also get full (untruncated) output from commands such as `ps aux` that frequently suffer from screens not being wide enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (if not all) cases where a *nix command prints colored output without the user specifically asking for it with an option involve aliases. In fact, many Linux distributions include an alias for `ls` and `grep` specifying colors in the global `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

These are from my Linux Mint Debian Edition:

```
$ grep alias /etc/bash.bashrc
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
```

So, if your program is calling these commands through BASH, you are running `ls --color=auto` instead of `ls`.

You can bypass aliases in BASH (maybe other shells too but I have not tried it) by the following methods (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162903/1081936)):

1. the full pathname of the command: `/bin/ls`
2. command substitution: `$(which ls)`
3. the command builtin: `command ls`
4. double quotation marks: `"ls"`
5. single quotation marks: `'ls'`
6. a backslash character: `\ls`

If you use one of these methods in your software you should not have to worry about escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

if you're on redhat or a relative, like fedora or centos, you might look at
modifying

```
/etc/sysconfig/init
```

look for the lines that say something like:

```
 # anything else => new style bootup without ANSI colors or positioning

 BOOTUP=color
```

and like it says, change the variable to anything other than "color"

this affects behavior of some of the system command line utilities, like service, ifup, ifdown, etc.